# Parallax image fills screen rather than div

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am creating a website as part of a University project and am tying to get a parallax effect on some images. I've been following the tutorial over at W3Schools...

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

My problem is that the images are filling the width of the screen rather than the div, causing them to be hugely zoomed in with the top and bottom cut off. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the zoom effect and show the parts of the image that are cut off, you can change the background-size property to:

```
background-size: contain;
```